# How can I create a function in MySQL for add elements in a table?

Tags: mysql, function

I would like to add elements in a table like this:

```
Codigo  Name   Lastname   Date    Sex    Salary
1       name1  lastname1  random  random random
2       name2  lastname2  random  random random
3       name3  lastname3  random  random random
4       name4  lastname4  random  random random
```

Date is a date random betweem years 2000 - 2015

Sex is random boolean 1 or 0

Salary is a random float between 500.00 and 5000.00

is that possible? How can I do that? I don't know even how can I do the sentence while

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION inserting(integer varying, character varying, character varying, date, boolean, float varying) RETURNS void
AS $$
begin
insert into trabajador(codigo, name, lastname, date, sex, salary) values ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6);
end;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Comment: Use the `RANDOM()` function to pick random numbers in the ranges you want. Then just do an `INSERT` statement with all those values. Which part of this are you having trouble with?

Comment: @Barmar I don't know how to doing, even the while

Comment: Your question is tagged mysql.  MySQL is in the title.  And yet, you are writing a Postgres function.  Please decide what database you are really using.

Answer (score 1):

Use `rand()` to generate a float number between 0 and 1.  Then something like this should generate your random data:

```
insert into yourtable values
( 1,
 'John',
 'Doe', 
 DATE_ADD('2000-01-01', INTERVAL (RAND()*15*365) DAY), 
 FLOOR(RAND()*10) % 2, 
 500+ROUND(RAND() * 4500,2)
);
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/929c6/2)

Answer (score 1):

This should be a procedure, not a function, since it doesn't return anything. Then use a WHILE loop in the procedure to insert many rows.

To create many

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE inserting(rowcount INT)
BEGIN
    SET @i = 0;
    SET @codigo = (SELECT MAX(codigo)+1 FROM trabajador);
    WHILE @i < rowcount
    DO
        SET @name = CONCAT('name', @codigo);
        SET @lastname = CONCAT('lastname', @codigo);
        SET @date = DATE_ADD('2000-01-01', INTERVAL (RAND()*15*365) DAY);
        SET @sex = FLOOR(RAND() * 2);
        SET @salary = 500.0 + RAND() * 4500.0;
        INSERT INTO trabajador (codigo, name, lastname, date, sex, salary) 
            VALUES (@codigo, @name, @lastname, @data, @sec, @salary);
        SET @i = @i + 1;
        SET @codigo = @codigo + 1;
    END WHILE;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

To add 500 rows, use `CALL inserting(500);`

Comment: How can I do the while, I mean if a wish insert 500 inserts? You know name1, name2, ..., name500?

Comment: You need to call the function for each name you're adding. Where are the names coming from?

Comment: it's only name1, name2, etc because I need to do tests, so.. I need a least 1 000 000 elements

Comment: Where are the names coming from? Are they in another table? Are they in a file?

Comment: no, I am creating these name, that is because I need the procedure

Comment: I've added a loop to create the names sequentially.

Comment: Can you help me please?

ou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE inserting(INT rowcount)
BEGIN
    SET @' at line 1

I'm reading http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/set-statement.html it's look good the syntaxis but I got an error

Comment: Sorry. MySQL doesn't have `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE`, just `CREATE PROCEDURE`. I also had `INT` in the wrong place in the arguments, and a typo in the middle. I just tested the update and it doesn't complain any more.

Answer (score 0):

Using `RAND()` function

```
CREATE TABLE tbl(Codigo INT(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
                ,Name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
                ,LastName VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
                ,Date DATE NOT NULL
                ,Sex BOOLEAN NOT NULL
                ,Salary FLOAT NOT NULL
                );

INSERT INTO tbl(Name, LastName, Date, Sex, Salary)
VALUES('name1',
       'lastname1',
       FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2000-01-01 00:00:00') + FLOOR(0 + (RAND() * 157680000))),
       FLOOR(RAND() * 10) % 2,
       FLOOR(RAND() * 5000) + 500);
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d22c4/1/0)</kbd>